# Printing Input From a Text File: "‚Äú" and "‚Äô" Printing instead of " and ' Respectively

Tags: java, escaping, ascii, java.util.scanner

I'm using the Scanner object to parse a large .txt file. However all quotation marks and apostrophes are being printed out as "‚Äú" and "‚Äô". Is there anyway to print the actual """ and "'"?

This is my scanning method:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("oldmanandthesea.txt"));

//the first line of the file is: “No,” the old man said.
System.out.println(in.nextLine); // prints: ‚ÄúNo,‚Äù the old man said.
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the scanning method?\

Comment: I just posted the code.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc of the Scanner constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) you're using says:

> Bytes from the file are converted into characters using the underlying platform's default charset.

Use the other constructor, that takes a charset as argument, and specify the charset of your file.

Another possibility is that your console is simply unable to display those special characters. Try to write to a file, and see if that works better.